# Emacs 24 Gui and Retina Display

Tags: docview, rendering

I've got a macbook pro with a retina display and Emacs 24.5. 
DocView rendering of pdf are very blurry. There is a few threads on the subjects but they deal with setting a higher resolution which didn't work for me.
I wrote on my .emacs

```
(setq doc-view-resolution 300)
(require 'doc-view)
```

But it had no effect.

Does anybody know how to deal with it ?
Any help would be grateful.
[image: Doc_View_low_rendering_with_retina]

Comment: Did you evaluate those commands (C-x C-e at the end of each ")") after you wrote them? Or restart emacs?

Comment: Yes I did. As you can see on the picture, the image looks very blurry. I switched to mudraw instead of ps but I get the same problem.

Comment: after `(setq doc-view-resolution 200)`, `(doc-view-clear-cache)`

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port this will actually help you . 
It has retina display build in support in the doc-view-mode.

Answer (score 0):

I will put this here for reference, this helps:

```
(setq doc-view-resolution 192)
```

Replace 192 with whatever works for you, credit goes to Yuri Khan:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/RlIliEIt_4Y